# OpenCV_TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, opencv

I was using OpenCV 2.4.6 and was running the following code successfully from OpenCV Python Tutorial-

```
    import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('slow.flv')
ret,frame = cap.read()

r,h,c,w = 250,90,400,125  # simply hardcoded the values
track_window = (c,r,w,h)
roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
hsv_roi =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array((0., 60.,32.)), np.array((180.,255.,255.)))

roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi],[0],mask,[180],[0,180])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )

while(1):
ret ,frame = cap.read()

if ret == True:
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1)

    # apply meanshift to get the new location
    ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)

    # Draw it on image
    x,y,w,h = track_window
    img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
    cv2.imshow('img2',img2)

    k = cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    else:
        cv2.imwrite(chr(k)+".jpg",img2)

else:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Later on I started to using OpenCV 3.0 and replace some Lib files in site packages directory and also replaced CV2.pyd file.Then when I tried to run the same code, i am getting the following error-

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Backup\OpenCV_Python_Prac_files\Prac5.1.1_ Video Analysis_MeanShift.py", line 14, in 
    roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_*getitem*_'**

Can anyone tell me what is the reason behind causing this problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)`  that's only valid in opencv3.0. if you use that code with 2.4.6, img2 will be None.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that your `frame` is `None`. Check the return value of the first call to `cap.read`

Comment: Can you be more specific which part I should modify?..anyway,i can still run this same code by using my webcam by changing the code "cap = cv2.VideoCapture('slow.flv')" to cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0).I think the problem is,my python module can not read the video files loaded from the computer.

Comment: After `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('slow.flv')`, you're performing a `read` operation but never check the return values, just do the same `if ret` as you do in your while-loop.

Comment: However,I think the code is fine...may be i am missing some file in the installation directory.